# Modify a dictionnary with python (and saving it for further session)

Tags: python, opencv, save

I got a programm that let's you choose color in the HSV space (for OpenCV). The first part, is about the creation of a dictionnary that contain some predefined colors :

```
# -*-coding:Utf-8 -*

# Initialisation du conteneur des couleurs, ici un dictionnaire
Color_Available = dict()

# Couleurs prédéfinies :
# Pour en rajouter, utiliser la même syntaxe.
# Green
greenLower = (29, 86, 6)
greenUpper = (64, 255, 255)
Color_Available["Green"] = (greenLower, greenUpper)

# Red
redLower = (46, 57, 90)
redUpper = (179, 255, 255)
Color_Available["Red"] = (redLower, redUpper)
```

Some line under it, a function is defined :

```
def Color_choice(parameters):
    # My code
```

My question is, how could I make a programm that ask the users a color name and 6 different HSV parameters (Low and High), and that add this new color to the dictionnary permanently.
The goal is that if I close the programm, and open it 10 days later, I still got this new color that was added last time.

In fact, I don't really know how I should save the color data, and how I can access it.

Anyhelp would be priceless,

Thanks !

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html  Check out dictwriter.  It's all in the documentation

Comment: If you are able to store your data in a reasonable Python Data Structure, like `dict`, `list`, etc., then you may serialize the data using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I'm new to python (and coding in general), and I've never seen this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use pandas to create a .csv file for that dictionary so something like:

```
import pandas as pd

colr = input ('Enter color name: ')
hsv1 = input ('Enter first HSV: ')
# do the same for the other inputs
dict = {'Color': clr, 'HSV1': hsv1, ...  }

# make dataframe and store as .csv
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df.to_csv('Directory for storing')
```

Then to read the csv it's as simple as

```
df = pd.read_csv('Diretcory and file name')
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I'm new to python (and coding in general), and I've never seen this yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need some way to preserve the data once the program exits. The easiest way to do this is to save the dictionary as a json file, and read it if the file exists.

At the top of your program, you would check if this file exists, and read it.

```
import json, atexit
from pathlib import Path

data_file = 'color_data.json'
if Path(data_file).is_file():
   with open(data_file, 'r') as fp:
       color_data = json.load(fp)
else:
   # No file exists, load some defaults
   color_data = {'Green': ((29, 86, 6), (64, 255, 255))}

def write_file_on_exit():
   with open(data_file, 'w') as f:
       json.dump(color_data, f)

atexit(write_file_on_exit)

# Your normal logic here
```

The `atexit` makes sure that when your program exits, the new data is written to the file and saved for the next time.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I'm new to python (and coding in general), and I've never seen this yet.